# How can I get the list of the types loaded by the CLR?

Tags: .net, debugging, reflection, clr

It is straightforward to get the list of the types defined in an assembly: `assembly.GetTypes()`.

What I am interested in is the list of types currently loaded by the runtime. More specifically, I would like to get the list of the closed generic types that are loaded.

I suppose that the CLR keeps a list of the loaded types. I think that I could use CLR MD to get this list, but I would like to get and use the list in the current process. Using CLR MD, I would have to start an external process, capture the loaded types list, dump it to a file, and then read it from the active process.

**Is there a debugging or diagnostic API that provides the list of loaded types for the current process?**

Answer (score 0):

Depending on if you need all types in all AppDomains or not, you might be able to query the current AppDomain for all loaded assemblies, and query those:

```
from a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
from t in a.GetTypes()
where t.IsGenericType
select t.FullName
```